# Retrieve uv coordinate at hit point of OSL trace() call

Tags: uv, osl

Using getmessage("trace",...) I can get the name of the geometry, it's location, the position of the hit, etc, but it doesn't appear that I can obtain the uv coordinate for a uv map of the hit geometry.

To be clear, I don't mean the uv parameter for the triangle that I hit, but the texture coordinate from a uv map.

Has anyone figured out a way to do this?

Comment: Did you try `geom:uv`?  Moreover, to increase chance of getting answer, providing .blend file may help.

Comment: Hi there @cppBeginner, I tried everything plausible.  In the end I looked through the source code and convinced myself that it wasn't actually supported by the current code.  In any case, as nice as it would be to have this as a feature, I figured out another way to solve the problem.

Comment: It sounds similar to `traceset` which is not supported yet.   How did you solve?  I am curious.

Comment: According to https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/render/cycles/nodes/osl.html, the `geom:uv` should work.  If it is not, it would be nice to be reported via https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/task/edit/form/1/.  From my experience, the developers use several days to react, but every report will be read.